# Получить значение атрибута

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
 <a class='active' rel='0' alt='96771'>Web</a>
```

Каким образом получить значение атрибута **alt** , то есть только **96771** ?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery

```
$(".active").attr("alt");
```

PHP

```
$link = "<a class='active' rel='0' alt='96771'>Web</a>";
preg_match("/alt='(.*?)'/i", $link, $match);

echo $match[1]; // 96771
```

Comment: нужно именно на php

Comment: @Денис, через регулярку только если